# Reductions to SAT

Tags: reference-request, satisfiability

There is a long-standing and seemingly ever-growing trend to reduce various (even undecidable) problems to SAT to get practically useful solvers, like for instance [1].

I'm looking for some kind of survey or list of papers/projects that fall into this category.

[1] Chad E. Brown: Satallax: An Automatic Higher-Order Prover. IJCAR 2012: 111-117